# Can you have a Socket.IO (express) server be loaded from a web browser?

Tags: javascript, sockets, node.js

You know, a web server. Right now my Socket.IO server loads from a BATCH file that is a JavaScript file. Can you use node and make the socket.io server load from a web browser. Like a web-server utility tool or something of the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's explicitly not possible due to the design of [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets). It starts as a special HTTP request that, after the handshaking, drops the HTTP protocol and strips it down into the WebSocket protocol -- a nearly bare protocol similar to (but slightly more managed than) raw TCP. Because a web browser specifically cannot handle HTTP requests, it could never initiate the socket as a server.

This was done specifically so it wouldn't be possible to write a drive-by botnet website to use scores of users' computers for DDOS attacks without their knowing, amongst other security concerns.

So it wouldn't surprise me if Flash supported that kind of behavior. ;) (I know Java can, but who enables Java applets?)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you *Can*. Not that I can think of a good use case.

You would need to put the startup code somewhere where the web server could run it and you would need to get the web server to return some information to the browser to allow it to then connect. You would also have to insert the socket.io code into the browser after the socket server had started.

So I *Think* that it would indeed be possible but rather complex for little gain. I suppose one possible use case would be to restart a socket server after failure. Actually I'd do that a slightly different way, probably by calling an external script from Node.

Answer (score 0):

fortunatly the answer is no. if you mean by load / launched , NO. but you can create a script on a server that launch another server once a url is requested by a a client.